How to modify existing and new string index in Redis?
I am storing strings and numbers in Redis.
I use basic key value stores to keep track of the current color value.
DATA:color:ID1 = red
DATA:color:ID2 = red
DATA:color:ID3 = red
DATA:color:ID4 = blue

I use SETs to allow for quick lookup of colors and corresponding IDs.
INDEX:color:red = {ID1, ID2, ID3}
INDEX:color:blue = {ID4}

How should I go about updating these values? If ID1 becomes blue, we will need to run the following commands:
SADD INDEX:color:blue ID1
SREM INDEX:color:red ID1
SET DATA:color:ID1 blue

The issue though is I do not know which SET ID1 is inside at the time of updating the value to blue. I can achieve this using a lua script, but this violates the rules about generating dynamic keys. The lua script would look like:
-- ARGV[1] is the index key
-- ARGV[2] is the ID
-- ARGV[3] is the new value

local k = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
redis.call('SREM', ARGV[1] .. ":" .. k, ARGV[2])
redis.call('SADD', ARGV[1] .. ":" .. ARGV[3], ARGV[2])
redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[3])

Example usage would look like:
EVALSHA <SHA> 1 DATA:color:ID1 INDEX:color ID1 blue

If I were storing numbers, this is trivial as I can use sorted sets.
Is there a way to achieve this without violating the guidelines?

The reason that rule exists is because you could get a CROSSSLOT error in a clustered environment. If you'll never be clustered, you can ignore it. That said, once you do this, you can never be clustered. So be sure.
If you will be clustered, you can solve this with hashtags. By putting part of the key in curly braces, you can guarantee that those keys will be on the same shard and never get a CROSSSLOT error. Of course, that means that these particular keys can never benefit from clustering. So, tradeoffs.
I'd probably use transactions to do this as well. Guarantees the atomicity of the change without having to write Lua. And, it allows out clients to get in while you are doing stuff. Doesn't tie up the single thread that is Redis as long.
WATCH DATA:{color}:ID1
GET DATA:{color}:ID1  // returns red
MULTI
  SADD INDEX:{color}:blue ID1
  SREM INDEX:{color}:red ID1
  SET DATA:{color}:ID1 blue
EXEC

Hope this helps!

In your MULTI block, I need to generate this command dynamically: SREM INDEX:{color}:red ID1 as I will not know the "red" in this key.

Yep. That's what the call to GET right before the MULTI is for.
